# How to push elements inside the array

Tags: php, arrays

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
 array (size=8)
  'id' => string '66' (length=2)
  'room_name' => string 'Luxury' (length=6)
  'no_of_room' => string '0' (length=1)
  'price' => string '1000' (length=4)
  'description' => string 'dfh dvsrtruub  dsgd' (length=19)
  'image' => string 'arrow.jpg' (length=9)
  'hotel_id' => string '1' (length=1)

 1 => 
 array (size=8)
  'id' => string '65' (length=2)
  'room_name' => string 'Deluxe' (length=6)
  'no_of_room' => string '3' (length=1)
  'price' => string '800' (length=3)
  'description' => string 'rybsvssfd' (length=9)
  'image' => string '2P2Z4.png' (length=9)
  'hotel_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

This is my array when i do var_dump. I want to push certain element to it. I would like something like this:

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
array (size=8)
  'id' => string '66' (length=2)
  'room_name' => string 'Luxury' (length=6)
  'no_of_room' => string '0' (length=1)
  'price' => string '1000' (length=4)
  'description' => string 'dfh dvsrtruub  dsgd' (length=19)
  'image' => string 'arrow.jpg' (length=9)
  'hotel_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'check_in_date'=> string '2014-1-1'(length=8)
  'check_out_date'=> string '2014-1-3'(length=8)
1 => 
array (size=8)
  'id' => string '65' (length=2)
  'room_name' => string 'Deluxe' (length=6)
  'no_of_room' => string '3' (length=1)
  'price' => string '800' (length=3)
  'description' => string 'rybsvssfd' (length=9)
  'image' => string '2P2Z4.png' (length=9)
  'hotel_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'check_in_date'=> string '2014-1-1'(length=8)
  'check_out_date'=> string '2014-1-3'(length=8)
```

I would like to add two more element at the end of each array.

two elements are:

```
  'check_in_date'=> string '2014-1-1'(length=8)
  'check_out_date'=> string '2014-1-3'(length=8).
```

I tried :(Assuming my array name is $jsonArray.

```
  $jsonArray = array_map(function ($subarray) {
  $subarray[] = "'check_in_date'=>'$check_in'";
  return $subarray;
  }, $jsonArray);
        var_dump($jsonArray);
```

But it didn't worked for me. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try  $subarray[] = array( check_in_date => $check_in );

Comment: It didn't gave me desired output. I inserted array within element. But i dont want array. I need only element to be added at last of element in each array as mentioned above. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if your 'check_in_date','check_out_date' are static

```
$x=array(array('id'=>'66'),array('id'=>'67'));
$x=array_map('push_elements',$x);
function push_elements($arr){
$arr['check_in_date']='2014-1-1';
$arr['check_out_date']='2014-1-3';
return $arr;
}
var_dump($x);
```

this is the output:
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "66" ["check_in_date"]=> string(8) "2014-1-1" ["check_out_date"]=> string(8) "2014-1-3" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "67" ["check_in_date"]=> string(8) "2014-1-1" ["check_out_date"]=> string(8) "2014-1-3" } }

Comment: I want this element to be pushed in an array. How this can push into an array. Rather i will fetch from the array if elements are found.

Comment: I think you should explain what is not working ? isn't this your desired output ?

Comment: No laurent . This was not the desired output. I had mentioned in question what output does i aspect. I think it need array_push function but i cant make it work. Please help me.

Comment: Try changing `$hotel` to `&$hotel`

Comment: please test my updated solution (replace $x with your array) and tell me if it returns what you expect

Comment: Sorry laurent for late reply. But this code returned me Null. And i need to pass checkin date and checkout date from variable and its dynamic. Is there anyother solution. Thank you.

Comment: please replace $x with your json array this should not return, if dates are variables how are they stored ? in another array?

Comment: thanks laurent for your response. But when i tried your code according to you by replacing $x with my array name. It gives me following error:

Comment: I am sorry but I am very sure that you are missing something because there couldn't be any error in the above code .. Assuming you have $jsonArray, you should start from the second line as follows: $jsonArray=array_map('push_elements',$jsonArray);
When you manage to do this I will try to update the answer for adding dynamic values